# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'II' (T_STRING)

Tags: templates, error, php-errors

I recently updated to EE 2.7.3 and noticed that I am getting the following error at the top of all my pages:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'II' (T_STRING) in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/eesystem/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php(3276) : eval()'d code on line 1

Line of said template reads:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Any clues what is causing this and how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that error message points to **line 1 of eval()'d code**, which is executed on line #3276 of Template.php:

```
eval("\$result = (".$cond.");");
```

This is part of parsing conditionals. So it looks like there's a problem with one of your conditionals. And since you say the error occurs on each page, the conditional most likely is present in a header/footer snippet/embed in your templates.

Check your templates and snippets for a conditional that uses `||` and verify its validity.